# ASP .NET core 3.0 dependency injection throws System.InsufficientExecutionStackException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a strange problem with the NET core dependency injection. When I'm trying to register a service, InsufficientExecutionStackException exception is thrown. What does this mean in this context? This is how I register the services (third line throws the exception):

```
        var connectionStr = Configuration.GetValue<string>("databaseConnectionString");
        services.AddSingleton<IDatabaseService>(s => new MySqlDatabaseService(connectionStr));
        services.AddSingleton<IUserService>(s => new UserService(s.GetRequiredService<IUserRepository>(), secret, s.GetRequiredService<IAchievementService>()));//this line throws the exception
        services.AddSingleton<IAchievementService, AchievementService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAchievementRepository, AchievementRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton<IUserRequestService, UserRequestService>();
        services.AddSingleton<AppSettingsService>();
```

Two services are injected in **UserService** class. These are the constructors of those:

```
    public UserService(IUserRepository userRepository, string secret, IAchievementService achievementService)
    {
        this.achievementService = achievementService;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.secret = secret;
    }
```

**UserRepository**:

```
    public UserRepository(IDatabaseService databaseService)
    {
        this.databaseService = databaseService;
    }
```

**AchievementService**:

```
        public AchievementService(IAchievementRepository achievementRepository, IUserService userService)
    {
        this.achievementRepository = achievementRepository;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.userRequestService = userRequestService;
    }
```

Another strange thing is that if I click "View details" from the Exception windows (I'm using Visual studio 2019) the debugger crashed and doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have a circular dependence between `UserService` and `AchievementService`. It's impossible for dotnet dependency injection to create an instance of the `UserService` without an instance of `AchievementService`. But to create an instance of `AchievementService`, you need an instance of `UserService`. So you're stuck in an infinite loop.

You should try to avoid this situation by removing the dependency. Do both services really need a dependency to the other one?

If it's not possible, you can try to use `Lazy<Service>` instead of just `Service`.

```cs
private readonly Lazy<IAchievementService> lazyAchievementService;

public UserService(Lazy<IAchievementService> lazyAchievementService, /*...*/)
{
    this.lazyAchievementService = lazyAchievementService;
    // ...
}

public void SomeFunction()
{
    var achievementService = lazyAchievementService.Value;
    achievementService.DoSomething();
}
```

This should allow you to create both class.

Comment: You are correct. I refactored the code so that the AchievementsService class doesn't anymore need the UserService class. Thanks